# CSS no selecciona al hijo

Tags: css

Cómo hago para que funcione, pongo en el CSS el hijo pero no me lo coge. Uno se llama `segundo` y el otro dentro de él `1`. ¿Cómo hago para que no herede?

```
#segundo {
  width: 1351px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  margin:-10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

#1 {
  background-color: Blue;
  position:relative;
  top: 90px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 351px;
  height: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: Hola alberto, por favor redacta mejor la pregunta ya que no se entiende que es lo tratas de hacer. Además si puedes coloca tambien el HTML al cual aplca ese CSS

Comment: no entiendo que necesitas, se mas claro por favor.

Comment: lo que quiero es que el div id="1" no funciona no sale el background ni la posición, son un div dentro del otro, div segundo primero y div 1 detro del id="segundo"

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que tienes un ID que es sólo números. Esto es válido en HTML5 (no en versiones anteriores donde los [nombres y IDs eran más estrictos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)), pero puede traer problemas en CSS donde [no lo es para los selectores de ID](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#css_identifiers). De ahí el error que ves.

Una solución si quieres usar un ID sólo numérico sería poner `\3` delante del número en el selector CSS. Realmente lo que estaríamos haciendo es escapando el número en ASCII (donde el carácter 31 en hexadecimal equivale al número 1, el 32 al 2, el 33 al 3, etc.) Puedes leer más información en [esta página del W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#css_identifiers) (en inglés).

Entonces no sería `#1` sino `#\31` y ya funciona:

```css
#segundo {
  width: 1351px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#segundo h1 {}

#\31 {
  background-color: Blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 351px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="segundo">
  <h1>Prueba</h1>
  <div id="1">Hola</div>
</div>
```

---

Otra opción sería utilizar un [selector de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) usando el ID, algo como esto `[id="1"]`:

```css
#segundo {
  width: 1351px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#segundo h1 {}

[id="1"] {
  background-color: Blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 351px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="segundo">
  <h1>Prueba</h1>
  <div id="1">Hola</div>
</div>
```

Personalmente preferiría evitarme problemas y consideraría cambiar el ID en el HTML. Aunque comprendo que no siempre es posible.

Comment: Muy buen truco eso de usar un selector de atributo, nunca se me hubiera ocurrido :)

Comment: ¿Que es realmente lo que hace `\3`?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero `\3` se usa para escapar los dígitos en un identificador CSS (que empiece con dígitos). Es una manera para poder usar IDs numéricos en CSS (porque se usaría el valor ASCII, que en el caso de 31 es 1). Voy a editar la respuesta para aclararlo y poner enlaces de referencia

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Muchas gracias, realmente desconocía que se pudiera hacer eso en CSS. "Nunca te irás a la cama sin haber aprendido algo nuevo" ;)

Answer (score 2):

No funciona posiblemente por el identificador de tu div, 1 en este caso. Poner solo un numero es valido para HTML pero no para CSS.

```css
#segundo {
width: 1351px;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
margin:-10px;
margin-top:-10px;
}
#segundo h1{

}
#primero{
background-color: Blue;
position:relative;
top: 90px;
left: 50px;
width: 351px;
height: 50px;   
}
```

```html
<div id="segundo">
  <div id="primero">
    <h1>Hola</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias era eso pero no lo entiendo no hay nada que se llame 1

Comment: Si te funciono no olvides puntuar la respuesta. #1{ } es el id del elemento, al que tratas de asignarle estilos con css